# No encuentra el metodo Get en Node.JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo el siguiente código en mi servidor de Node.JS que consulta a una base de datos:

```
              if(response.context.rfc){
                var valorRFC = response.context.rfc;
                connection.query(`SELECT * FROM pruebas.Usuarios2 where RFC = '${valorRFC}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
                      if (result.length > 0) {

                app.get('/bd/', (req, res)=>{
                        res.json("jeje");
                 });

                    } else {
                      console.log("No login");
                    }
              });
            }
```

Este resultado lo cacho desde mi archivo JavaScript con el siguiente fetch:

```
if(response.context.rfc){
    fetch('/bd/').then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
         console.log(data);
        }).catch(err => {
      });  
    }
};
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error en la consola de JavaScript:

> script.js:33 GET http://localhost:1000/bd/ 404 (Not Found)

¿Saben cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en la línea 33 de script.js?

Comment: @RuslanLópez `fetch('/bd/').then(r => r.json())`